# Not able to delete image from external storage programmatically in android studio

Tags: java, android, file

I am beginner in Android Studio I just want help in deletion of image from the folder here is my 
code I have done addition of image and added a button to save it in the external folder and just want to delete it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barcode);

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 60, bytearrayoutputstream);

            file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/SampleImage.png");

            try

            {
                file.createNewFile();

                fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                fileoutputstream.write(bytearrayoutputstream.toByteArray());

                fileoutputstream.close();

            }

            catch (Exception e)

            {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}
```

}
it would be very helpful if you support me in gaining the knowledge

Comment: File.delete() ?

Comment: `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` No. You cannot say that here as maybe there was an exception. Put the toast in the try block and put a diferent Toast in the catch block to inform the user and yourself when it fails.

Comment: `file.createNewFile();` Remove that line. The file will be created by the new FileOutputStream().

Comment: Don't understand why people keep appending "in Android Studio" to their question title when the question has nothing to do with Android Studio....

Answer (score 0):

```java
final String where = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?";
final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
        f.getAbsolutePath()
};
final ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
final Uri filesUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
contentResolver.delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);
// if (f.exists()) {
//     contentResolver.delete(filesUri, where, selectionArgs);
//     f.delete();
// }
```

Comment: we have write this in try block ??

Comment: no need .if you want you can put because some time file is not  there app getting crash so before this method you have to check file is there or not.

Comment: Your answer is only confusing for OP as it has nothing to do with deleting the file in a normal way.